# Quality of suggested alternative to Softmax

Tags: functions, derivatives, machine-learning

The commonly used smooth alternative for the function $\max(x,y)$ is the [LogSumExp function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp), which can be (loosely) defined as:
$$\frac{\ln(\exp(kx)+\exp(ky))}{k}$$
For higher values of $k$, this function tends towards the actual $\max$ function.
Now I was thinking of an alternative, namely:
$$\frac{y-x}{1+\exp(-k(y-x))}+x=(y-x)\sigma(-k(y-x))+x$$
where $\sigma$ is the [standard logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).
As shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/epv28uem7o), this is also a good approximation of the $\max$ function.

Now my question is this:

**What are the possible pros and cons of using my function instead of the LogSumExp function?**

Context: I was thinking of this problem as alternatives to the common [activation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), but answers explaining the difference between the two functions based on other perspectives are also welcome.

Comment: One possible con I see: If we fix $y=1$ as an example, we see that the LogSumExp function is monotonically increasing in $x$ for real $k$, while the new function is not monotonically increasing

Comment: @ydd thanks for the insight. Actually, fixing x or y to a constant value relates my function to the [swish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swish_function) and the LogSumExp to the [softplus](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softplus.html)